# Finding words which match regex in multiple text files

Tags: regex, text, terminal, command-line-arguments

So, I'm new to manipulating data from the command line, and also a beginner at regex.

I have multiple .txt files in multiple subdirectories. What I want to do is to find all words which have a certain number of consecutive consonants.

What I've tried so far is something like this:

```
  find . | grep -orhn '[bdfghjklmnprstvxzþ]\{2\}' > ../words.txt
```

Which only prints out something like:

```
  2:rt
  2:gr
  2:xl
  3:gr
  3:st
  3:kk
```

I want to get the whole word, not just the two consecutive consonants (and the numbers and colon. I don't know where that comes from since it's not in the original data, but it really doesn't matter for what I am trying to do).

Do you have a tip?

Comment: because of character class it matches only two characters. Why you added `{2}` after the charcter class?

Comment: try `grep -rP "bdfghjklmnprstvxzþ" *`

Comment: Because I was trying to find all words with two consecutive consonants. If i remove it, I get all of the consonants in all files, but if I change this to, say, {3} I get all triplets of consonants in all of the files in this particular directory (and subdirectories). I just don't get the whole word, which is what I want to do.

If the {2} means it will only output the pair, and nothing else, I'll have to find another way to do this.

Got any ideas?

I tried the Perl regex. I don't get it to do this either.

Comment: I forgot to mention that if I remove the -o flag the command outputs either the whole line or the whole file (not sure at this point) which includes the word that has the 2 consecutive consonants.

Comment: yep, without -o flag, it prints the whole line. Are you figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -n option is the line number in the text.

My suggestion is to try matching the word characters before and after.

This is what I tried and seemed to work.

```
grep -orh  '\w\+[bdfghjklmnprstvxzþ]\{2\}\w\+'
```

The -o option will only show what is matching, which is the entire word. 
The -r will look recursively which isn't relevant here given that find is doing the recursion for you.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thanks a lot.